# Sitecore Logging (Log4Net) Log to Database as Well as Text Files

Tags: sql-database, logging, log4net

Sitecore 7.5

The text file logging is working fine. But, I would like the logging to go to a SQL Server database so that I can search the data with T-SQL.

How would I do that?

I imagine it would be a change to the web.config file inside the `<log4net>` block. And, also an additional connection string.

```xml
<log4net>
<!-- LOGGING SETTINGS
     The file element defines the location of the log files. This location must
     be the same as the setting in LogFolder. The file element is a relative or
     absolute path that always uses slashes (/) as separators. A valid file
     element for a relative path would be:

       <file value="/data/logs/log.{date}.{processid}.txt"/>

     A valid element for an absolute path would be:

       <file value="C:/inetpub/wwwroot/data/logs/log.{date}.{processid}.txt"/>

     The macros supported are:

       {date}: Replaced with the current date (in the format yyyyMMdd)
       {time}: Replaced with the current time (in the format HHmmss)
       {processid}: Replaced with the current Windows process id

     For further information refer to the Log4Net documentation.
-->
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
  <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/log.{date}.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
  </layout>
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
</appender>
<appender name="WebDAVLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
  <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/WebDAV.log.{date}.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
  </layout>
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
</appender>
<appender name="SearchLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
  <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/Search.log.{date}.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
  </layout>
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
</appender>
<appender name="CrawlingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
  <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/Crawling.log.{date}.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
  </layout>
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
</appender>
<appender name="PublishingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
  <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/Publishing.log.{date}.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
  </layout>
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
</appender>
<appender name="NHibernateLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
  <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/NHibernate.log.{date}.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
  </layout>
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
</appender>
<root>
  <priority value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
</root>
<logger name="Sitecore.Diagnostics.WebDAV" additivity="false">
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="WebDAVLogFileAppender" />
</logger>
<logger name="Sitecore.Diagnostics.Search" additivity="false">
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="SearchLogFileAppender" />
</logger>
<logger name="Sitecore.Diagnostics.Crawling" additivity="false">
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="CrawlingLogFileAppender" />
</logger>
<logger name="Sitecore.Diagnostics.Publishing" additivity="false">
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="PublishingLogFileAppender" />
</logger>
<logger name="NHibernate" additivity="false">
  <level value="WARN" />
  <appender-ref ref="NHibernateLogFileAppender" />
</logger>
<logger name="NHibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
  <level value="WARN" />
  <appender-ref ref="NHibernateLogFileAppender" />
</logger>
</log4net>
```

Comment: You could also give some consideration to taking this further and look into https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash then you can throw all logs into one searchable place; think IIS logs, event logs, Sitecore logs in one glorious searchable place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I talk about this in a series of posts (https://grantkillian.wordpress.com/2014/12/26/sitecore-logging-to-the-database-part-1/, https://grantkillian.wordpress.com/2014/12/26/sitecore-logging-to-the-database-part-2-earning-the-good-developer-badge/, and https://grantkillian.wordpress.com/2014/12/26/sitecore-logging-to-the-database-part-3-the-performance-picture/)

The other answers here are all good, but for any large Sitecore implementation I would encourage you to look at any performance implications and the asynchronous logging solution.  If you don't want to dig into the async stuff, and last I looked there was some custom development needed to complete that properly for Sitecore, I'd recommend:

1. Use SQL Server stored procedure
2. Tune the Log4Net BufferSize setting
3. Consider data retention as log records could accumulate quickly: do you archive or remove the old data every month?  Be sure to have proper SQL Server maintenance plans etc (https://ola.hallengren.com/) to keep the system optimal

Answer (score 8):

Yes. You need a new `<appender>`. First you need to set up a table to receive the logging information:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log] (
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Thread] [varchar] (255) NOT NULL,
    [Level] [varchar] (50) NOT NULL,
    [Logger] [varchar] (255) NOT NULL,
    [Message] [varchar] (4000) NOT NULL,
    [Exception] [varchar] (2000) NULL
)
```

Then set up the `<appender>`.

```xml
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="100" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <connectionString value="data source=[database server];initial catalog=[database name];integrated security=false;persist security info=True;User ID=[user];Password=[password]" />
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
    </parameter>
</appender>
```

All of this sourced from the [original documentation for log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#MS%20SQL%20Server).

### Additional information

- [Storing Log4Net Messages in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279524/storing-log4net-messages-in-sql-server).
- [How to use Log4Net utility for logging into database using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516578/how-to-use-log4net-utility-for-logging-into-database-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Any idea how to figure out what version of log4net is being used?

Comment: That's actually a very good question. Normally I'd say "look at the version on log4net.dll" - but I can see that Sitecore has done some reimplementation and use Sitecore.Logging.dll. I'll try and find an answer for you.

Comment: Message: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: I am going to mark this as the answer. But, I am having a lot of trouble getting this working. I will post more questions when I can.

Comment: Sorry, changed the marked as answer. In my opinion, it's best not to start doing this at all.

Answer (score 4):

You can start by creating a table for logging, Preferably in  your own separate Database, Then you can update your Log4Net configurations to use the SQL appender, Alex Shyba [article](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/sitecore_logging_write_it_to_sql/) shows how you can do that, Basically you will need the following:

1. Create Your own Table for logging inside your own Database, Let say **SitecoreSystem**

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log] ( 
[ID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
[Date] [datetime] NOT NULL ,  
[Thread] [varchar] (255) NOT NULL ,  
[Level] [varchar] (20) NOT NULL ,  
[Logger] [varchar] (255) NOT NULL ,  
[Message] [varchar] (4000) NOT NULL  
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

2. Create your SQL Appender in web.config (or in your Log4Net config):

```xml
<appender name="SQL_Appender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
   <param name="ConnectionType" value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
   <param name="ConnectionString" value="user id=***;password=***;Data Source=****;Database=SitecoreSystem" />
   <param name="CommandText" value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message)" />
   <param name="Parameter">
      <param name="ParameterName" value="@log_date" />
      <param name="DbType" value="DateTime" />
      <param name="Layout" type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff}" />
      </param>
   </param>
   <param name="Parameter">
      <param name="ParameterName" value="@thread" />
      <param name="DbType" value="String" />
      <param name="Size" value="255" />
      <param name="Layout" type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%t" />
      </param>
   </param>
   <param name="Parameter">
      <param name="ParameterName" value="@log_level" />
      <param name="DbType" value="String" />
      <param name="Size" value="50" />
      <param name="Layout" type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%p" />
      </param>
   </param>
   <param name="Parameter">
      <param name="ParameterName" value="@logger" />
      <param name="DbType" value="String" />
      <param name="Size" value="255" />
      <param name="Layout" type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%c" />
      </param>
   </param>
   <param name="Parameter">
      <param name="ParameterName" value="@message" />
      <param name="DbType" value="String" />
      <param name="Size" value="4000" />
      <param name="Layout" type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m" />
      </param>
   </param>
</appender>
```

3. In your Log4Net root section, switch the default appender to the new one:

```xml
<root>
  <priority value="INFO"/>
  <appender-ref ref="SQL_Appender" />  
  <!--<appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender"/>-->  
</root>
```