# Sitecore Logging into azure blog storage in JSON format

Tags: azure, logging

We have a requirement to log all the errors/warnings on to Azure Blog Storage in JSON format (with specific structure) including the sitecore generated ones.

This will enable us to use any third party log analyzer such as sumo logic.

I had a look at this [Sitecore Logging (Log4Net) Log to Database as Well as Text Files](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1953/sitecore-logging-log4net-log-to-database-as-well-as-text-files) which is specific to SQL Database.

Would be good if you could share the solutions that's been implemented in production as there were performance issues with storing logs on to blog storage a while ago (2 years).

Comment: Are you asking, how to set up Sitecore logging with JSON or are you asking how to solve performance issues involved in logging to Azure Blog Storage?  If both, please split into 2 different questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the following project with your Sitecore solution.
https://github.com/olegburov/Sitecore-Azure-Diagnostics/

It adds a custom logger to log4net, which writes Sitecore's diagnostic data into [Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/) using [Append Blob](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2015/04/13/introducing-azure-storage-append-blob/).

Another option is to upgrade to the latest and greatest Sitecore XP 8.2 Update-1, where a new logger powered by [Azure Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/) comes out of the box.

Comment: But but but 8.2 Update 1 is not released yet! It's good to know what's coming in it though ;-)

Comment: It's coming and you will see all details very soon.

Comment: still no sign of update 1 @OlegBurov

Comment: @nil-pun It's now available at: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/82/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_82_Update1.aspx

Comment: @OlegBurov, excellent. Are you able to confirm whether update 1 has a azure blob appender for storing files on to blob. Our requirement is to store all the logs files on to Azure Blog storage so that Sumo logic can extract.

Comment: @nil-pun No, SXP 8.2 Update-1 uses Application Insights for storing Sitecore logs. You can read about it here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/